# Cohort analysis by day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using a code for create a cohort analysis based on customer retention. As I have the code right now, I see the analysis based by day. I need a desired output based in a month. In the output attached below, you will see that I `index = day` and should be `index = month`. The 1,2,3,4 columns should represent 1 day on a month so I need to get from 1 to 31 as output columns.

.csv file sample:

```
    timestamp   user_hash   
0   2019-02-01  NaN         
1   2019-02-01  e044a52188dbccd71428    
2   2019-02-01  NaN C0D1A22B-9ECB-4DEF      
3   2019-02-01  d7260762b66295fbf9e5    
4   2019-02-01  d7260762b66295fbf9e5
```

Actual output sample:

```
CohortIndex   1      2        3       4
CohortMonth             
2019-02-01  399.0   202.0   160.0   117.0
2019-02-02  215.0   109.0   89.0    61.0
2019-02-03  146.0   79.0    62.0    50.0
2019-02-04  175.0   67.0    50.0    32.0
2019-02-05  179.0   52.0    39.0    32.0
2019-02-06  137.0   31.0    29.0    16.0
2019-02-07  139.0   42.0    33.0    25.0
2019-02-08  143.0   35.0    32.0    24.0
2019-02-09  105.0   31.0    23.0    12.0
```

The code used is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df_events = pd.read_csv('.../events.csv')

#convert object column to datatime and remove time from the column
df_events['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_events['timestamp'].str.strip(), format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M' )

df_events['timestamp'] = df_events['timestamp'].dt.date

#drop NaN from user_hash column
clean_data = df_events[df_events['user_hash'].notna()]

#function to check if we have NaN where whe shouldn't
def missing_data(x):
    return x.isna().sum()

#uses the datatime function to gets the month a datatime stam and strips the time
def get_month(x):
    return dt.datetime(x.year,x.month,1)#year, month, increment of day

#create a new column
clean_data['LoginMonth'] = clean_data['timestamp'].apply(get_month)

#create new columns called CohortMonth and groupby information
clean_data['CohortMonth'] = clean_data.groupby('user_hash')['timestamp'].transform('min')

#create the cohort

def get_date(df,column):
    year = df[column].dt.year
    month = df[column].dt.month
    day = df[column].dt.day
    return year, month, day

#create 2 variables, one for a month and one for a year. As we have 3 variables to return to the function we need to indicate to python that, _ is for day

login_year,login_month, _ = get_date(clean_data,'LoginMonth')


clean_data['CohortMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(clean_data['CohortMonth'])
cohort_year,cohort_month, _ = get_date(clean_data,'CohortMonth')
year_diff = login_year - cohort_year
month_diff = login_month - cohort_month
clean_data['CohortIndex'] = year_diff*12 + month_diff +1

#create cohort analysis data table
cohort_data = clean_data.groupby(['CohortMonth','CohortIndex'])['user_hash'].apply(pd.Series.nunique).reset_index()

cohort_count = cohort_data.pivot_table(index='CohortMonth',
                                      columns='CohortIndex',
                                      values='user_hash')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for posting the code and expected output. Please also post sample data from `df_events` to help us run the code.

Comment: Hello Nilesh, I did that.

Comment: (1) I tried running the code posted in the question on a sample `DataFrame` posted below in the answer section. However, I am getting negative index. Could you run the code on your side on this sample `DataFrame`. (2) Also, could you also explain what is `399.0` for example?. Is it the number of `unique` `user_hash` for a particular date? Then trying to understand why there are `4` columns.

Comment: 'import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import hashlib

# Create DataFrame
df_events = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(pd.np.random.randint(1,100,size=50), unit='d'),
    'user_hash': [hashlib.md5(str(i).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() for i in np.random.randint(0,10,50)]
})
df_events['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_events['timestamp'])
df_events.head()'